# Calculate number of rows of each new dataframe from loop and save everything in one loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have made the following loop that filters my data for each year (between 81 and 91) and creates a new dataframe from each iteration.

```
for(i in 81:91){
  assign(paste0("SampleSizeGaza",i), GazaTB1[GazaTB1$year==i,])
}
```

Is there any way I could modify this loop (or create a new one) that calculates the number of rows of each of these new datafames (using nrows preferably) and that it saves it onto ONE dataframe (eg SampleSize) that has two columns, being year (from 81 to 91) and the YearSampleSize (which would be nrow of each dataframe per year).
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 81:91){
  assign(paste0("SampleSizeGaza",i), GazaTB1[GazaTB1$year==i,])
  dfi <- data.frame(year = i, YearSampleSize = NROW(eval(as.name(paste0("SampleSizeGaza", i)))))
  df <- rbind(df, dfi)
}
```

everything is in base R however I do need to mention that this is very inefficient compared to using dplyr/tidyverse. Here is a comparison on a very large dataframe:

```
> ### Create large dataframe
> GazaTB1 <- data.frame(year = sample(81:91, size = 50000000, replace = TRUE))

> ### for loop
> ptm <- proc.time()
> df <- data.frame()
> for(i in 81:91){
+   assign(paste0("SampleSizeGaza",i), GazaTB1[GazaTB1$year==i,])
+   dfi <- data.frame(year = i, YearSampleSize = NROW(eval(as.name(paste0("SampleSizeGaza", i)))))
+   df <- rbind(df, dfi)
+ }
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   2.80    1.27    4.08 
> 
> ### tidyverse
> library(tidyverse)
> 
> ptm2 <- proc.time()
> df2 <- GazaTB1 %>% 
+   group_by(year) %>% 
+   count()
> proc.time() - ptm2
   user  system elapsed 
   0.64    0.14    0.78
```

Comment: Thanks ! The first code you posted works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Grouped operations are easier to manage if you keep your data in one object, rather than using `assign` to create multiple objects. There are two common methods to do this.

## Base R

The following code uses `split` to split the data frame into a list with a separate data frame for every unique value of the data frame's "group" column, then uses `sapply` to count the rows in the list. The result is a named vector.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = T),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

head(df)
  group      value
1     a  0.3691390
2     b -0.2444268
3     d -0.4776481
4     b -1.5580131
5     a  1.1913923
6     a -2.1483141

df.split <- split(df, df$group)
counts <- sapply(df.split, nrow)

 a  b  c  d 
24 28 16 32
```

## Tidyverse

Alternately we can use the **tidyverse** packages to perform a grouped operation directly on the data frame, returning a summarized data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df.counts <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  count()

  group     n
  <chr> <int>
1 a        24
2 b        28
3 c        16
4 d        32
```